# How to use YAML data in PlantUML diagram?

Tags: preprocessor, plantuml

The following PlantUML doesn't work. Wherein lies the problem?

```
!define YAML_DATA {
actor: User
usecases:
  - name: Browse Products
  - name: Purchase Product
}

!define ACTOR_NAME {%YAML_DATA.actor%}
!define UC_NAMES {%YAML_DATA.usecases.name%}

@startuml

actor %ACTOR_NAME%

%for uc in UC_NAMES%
usecase %uc%
%endfor%

%ACTOR_NAME% -> %uc%

@enduml
```

I tried replacing the "define" with a "function" but I'm lost because there's no documentation that covers this type of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as far as I am aware, PlantUML [preprocessing](https://plantuml.com/preprocessing) does not support YAML, only JSON.

In that respect the [Preprocessing JSON](https://plantuml.com/preprocessing-json) section of the manual should be of more help.

Second, even if it did, the `%` syntax is (mostly) used for functions, not variables. Instead of `!define %foo%` (which is meant for function declaration) `!$foo=...` should be used to declare variables.

Finally, there is no such thing as `%for`. Instead, [`!foreach`](https://plantuml.com/preprocessing-json#d490ce0984282944) should be used

As a side-note, the data lives outside the `@startuml` which *could* cause issues depending on how the diagram is run.

So, as to address these issues, I *think* that what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
@startuml

!$JSON_DATA = {
"actor": "User",
"usecases": [
  {"name": "Browse Products"},
  {"name": "Purchase Product"}
]}

!$ACTOR_NAME=$YAML_DATA.actor

actor $ACTOR_NAME

!foreach $uc in $JSON_DATA.usecases
   usecase "$uc.name"
   $ACTOR_NAME -> "$uc.name"
!endfor
@enduml
```

Which gives:

[image]

It is also worth mentioning that the JSON does not *have* to be defined inside the diagram. It can also be loaded from an external file using `%load_json("data.json")` or `%load_json("http://example.com/data.json")`.